# Upgrading from d6 to d7: getting puzzling 'requirements problem' error

Tags: 7, upgrading

I am trying to upgrade from d6 to d7 and I'm getting a requirements problem immediately after running upgrade.php. It seems there's some crucial information missing. For me, at least: absolutely no clue what is happening here.

I've got the [Ad](http://drupal.org/project/ad) module (as well as [ad_image](http://drupal.org/project/ad_image), [ad_flash](http://drupal.org/project/ad_flash)) enabled

The error that is thrown back at me is:

> upload (Missing): Unresolved dependency, Flash Ad requires this module.
>   upload (Missing): Unresolved dependency, Image Ad requires this module.

See screenshot [image: Drupal 6 to 7 upgrade, fishy error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before upgrading the drupal core, you must deactivate your contrib modules. I think you did not.?

Upgrade the core first. Then upgrade any contrib modules.
If you have used cck in drupal 6, you will need the [cck](http://drupal.org/project/cck) module to do the migration.

Comment: I obviously did not. Sorry for not having read the instructions more carefully, totally missed that.